# Method call would cause a deadlock to occur

Tags: com, casting, deadlock, breakpoints

I´m facing the following error with my application ASP.net:

**Unable to cast COM object of type 'LBCOMLib.LBCOM_SessionClass' to interface type 'LBCOMLib.ILBCOM_Session'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B46EBC80-9D0D-11D3-B0D3-0000B422F6DA}' failed due to the following error: The component is configured to use synchronization and this method call would cause a deadlock to occur. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004E005)**

This is happening when I call a page of search on the application. Weeks ago it was working, but now even if I put breakpoints at all methods of the page.cs even Page_Load while debugging the system doesn´t stop at the breakpoint and pops up whith the error described before.

Does somebody explains what´s the problem?

Comment: Essentially your problem is that you are causing multiple threads to try to access a COM object which is configured in COM+ to allow only a single thread at a time, in a way which could cause deadlock (which likely means your COM object is in turn making calls outside its context while processing a call in). Your architecture is probably wrong, and there won't be any quick fix. It won't be possible to provide useful answers without a lot more information, e.g.:how the .NET code accesses the COM object;what's the COM object's lifetime;what calls into it, and when;what calls out does it make...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Try to UnCheck

> COM object viewable checkbox

under the VisualStudio Settings

**Solution 2:** 
Try to browse from over the Asp.Net server URL link

This is interesting with the **ComVisible** attribute in your AddIn project probably Activex Ocx etc.